# Limits involving $e$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I am looking to solve the following limits.

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}5e^{-x}$

and

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to2}\frac{1}{2e-ex}$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}5e^{-x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}5e^x=\infty$

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to2}\frac1{2e-ex}=-\frac1e\lim_{x\to2}\frac1{x-2}=\mp \infty$

Answer (score 1):

The first limit diverges to $\infty$. You can see this by looking at the graph.

Also, for the second limit,
when $x \to 2^+$, it diverges to $-\infty$,
when $x \to 2^-$, it diverges to $\infty$.

The left and right limits are not the same, so the second limit does not exist.